# GCC Optimization and debugging

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, compiler-optimization

I don't understand exactly the following:

> When using debugging and optimization together, the internal rearrangements carried out by the optimizer can make it difficult to see what is going on when examining an optimized program in the debugger. For example, the ordering of statements may be changed.

What i understand is when i build a program with the `-g` option, then the executable will contain a *symbolic table* which contains variable, function names, references to them and their line-numbers.
And when i build with an optimization option, for example the ordering of instructions may be changed depends on the optimization.

What i don't understand is, why debugging is more difficult.
I would like to see an example, and an easy to understand explanation.

Comment: Because the generated code does not have a 1:1 correspondence with the source code.

Comment: Instructions aren't just reordered. Some statements might get optimised away completely. Some instructions might be replaced with different instructions that produce the same results more efficiently. Your symbolic table of line numbers isn't helpful if the compiler produces instructions that doesn't correspond to the statements in your source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple example:

```
int a = 4;
int b = a;
int c = b;
printf("%d", c);
```

can be optimized as:

```
printf("%d", 4);
```

In fact in optimized compiles, the compiler might well do exactly this (in machine code of course)

When debugging we the debugger will allow us to inspect the memory associated by a,b and c but when the top version get optimized into the bottom version a,b and c no longer exist in RAM. This makes inspecting RAM a lot harder to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

An example that might happen:

```
int calc(int a, int b)
{
    return a << b + 7;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    int val = calc(x, y);
    return val;
}
```

Optimized this might be the same as

```
int main()
{
    return 642;
}
```

A contrived example, but trying to debug that kind of optimization in actual code isn’t simple. Some debuggers may show all lines of code marked when stepping through, some might skip them all, some may be confused. And the developer at least is.

Answer (score 4):

When you compile using the optimization flag you are ensured that the output of the program will be compliant to the code you wrote, but the code itself will variate from the one you actually compiled.

As you pointed out, the code will be rearranged and some call will be performed differently. Also another optimization could be loop unrolling, branch prediction and functions calls simplification. These optimizations will also vary on the architecture you are running on.

For all these reasons (and others) your code may become very difficult to debug, since it is transparent for you what the compiler exactly does, thus meaning that the code you want to debug may not look like the one you wrote.